# Alternatives to Google/iOS maps

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, gps

Does anyone know what alternatives there are (preferably free/open source) to google maps or iOS maps?

What I need to do is make a native app for both Android and iOS with turn based navigation. Although Google map and iOS maps are very good at this, I need the GPS to be handled in the app. So te application can't rely on closing the current app, and then opening the phones default maps applications.

Having looked into Android, it seems I can get Google maps for Business that can possibly do this, but the license is very expensive.

Is there an alternative that I can use to run GPS maps inside my own app? The app will have to allow button clicks to mark points on a map as the user is navigating hence I can't switch between the app and the devices native maps. The switching process is too long to be accurate.

Have looked at Garmin but their solution seems to work on Windows phones only.

Comment: "I can't switch between the app and the devices native maps" ... why can't you use iOS MapKit framework and customize it per your apps need with in your own app? Everything is available to you to customize

Comment: In iOS 7+ you can use `MKDirections` to get directions in your app and display maps in your app using the `MapKit` framework. Presumably Google provides similar functionality on Android.

Comment: Just Google for 'osmdroid'.

Comment: There's also ordance surveys various offerings but only relevant to the UK.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Mapquest](http://developer.mapquest.com/) maps for android apps before, I think they have a pretty good API and great support!